# HTML5 <input> tag type ="time"

Tags: html

I use html5 input tag like this:

```
<input type="time" name="usr_time" value="19:47:13">
```

But it is invalid value when I submit. 
Besides, I cannot change the second in that box, it is disable. 
Can someone explain it?

Comment: Seems fine to me (Google Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/7JpZz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set the step attribute. If it isn't detailed enough, you can also use float values for it.

```
<input type="time" step="1" />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html

Comment: This helped me get and be able to edit the seconds, but there is still a problem with Chrome's implementation of this time field. It forces you to use the field as if you're actually needing it in the "time-of-a-day" sense and also in 12 hours format. That is far from safe presumption and is making life more difficult for developers. Why would they presume so and limit our capabilities, I have no idea. 
What if I want to save/edit some stop-clock timing result, which is maybe 15 hours, 32 mins?
Sadly, my solution was to go back to good old type=text.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="time" name="usr_time" value="19:47:AM/PM">
```

Here, `value="1:47:AM"` so you cannot change the seconds , it is in 12 hours format and if we add step=1 as mentioned above then `value="1:47:55:AM"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is only (for this time) supported in MS Edge and Chrome I wrote a tiny component — [Timepicker](https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js) — that you can easily use for major browsers.

The usage is like this:

```js
var timepicker = new TimePicker('time', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});

var input = document.getElementById('time');

timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
  
  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 1.2em/1.3 sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#efefef, #999) fixed;
}
input {
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```